# programmatically add resource in webapp/myapp/META-INF/context.xml and use by getting by InitialContext

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, jdbc

I am adding a new resource by editing an XML file programmatically:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/AAA"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          .......
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AAA"/>
```

and I want to use just after adding.

```
 InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
 ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/AAA");
```

but it returns an error:

> Name [jdbc/AAA] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

Comment: When you add this ressource before starting your tomcat or after tomcat has started?

Comment: I need insert when tomcat is already running.

Comment: The configuration will be loaded at startup!